# How to run Spock tests with robolectric 4.3

Tags: spock, robolectric

I have run spock tests with robolectric in the past with robospock and electricspock in other projects with older versions of robolectric. My new project uses robolectric 4.3 but it according to release notes confirmed by experiments neither robospock nor electricspock support robolectric 4.3 yet. Has any one had success running spock tests with robolectric 4.3? If so, could you please share your setup. TIA.

Comment: _"Please share your setup"?_ Dear Farrukh, I am afraid this is not how SO works and as a user with 2.4k reputation you probably know already. Please share **your** setup first, both the working one with the old roboelectric version (including an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a small application class and a working test) as well as the one that is not working. Then maybe someone can help you. Please also describe what "not working" means. Compile problems? Runtime problems? Error logs?

Comment: Sorry but its been a bit of slog trying both robospock and electricspock and unfortunately I did not keep changes. The documents on robospock https://github.com/robospock/RoboSpock clearly says "0.7.0 - Robolectric updated to 3.0". The document on electricspock has an open issue to support robolectric 4.0 https://github.com/hkhc/electricspock/issues/10. I am quite certain neither project supports robolectric 4.0. My question was simply asking is there an alternative to these two projects to make Spock work with robolectric 4.0.

Comment: Questions asking for tools or other external resources are considered off-topic on SO as they tend to attract opinionated answers and discussions. Please either change your question as indicated by me or just delete it. P.S.: What kind of developer has a working old project, makes changes and cannot go back? There is Git and IDEs like IntelliJ even have a local history feature. Your statement sounds like a pretty lame excuse to me. Sorry, no code, no answer. Good luck to you.

Comment: I updated my post to clarify that my working cases were in other projects with older versions of robolectric and that I am currently looking for a solution that supports Spock testing with robolectric 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out some forks of ElectricSpock and this [fork](https://github.com/thitu/electricspock) supports Roboelectric 4.x. Hopefully this helps someone.

> The latest version of this fork is 4.7.3-3 which has been updated to support Robolectric version 4.7.3